# Excel: Custom function that fixes itself?

Tags: excel, vba, function

Long story short, I'm trying to have my custom function augment the formula entry (the one that triggered it!) as part of the function. Here's a distilled example:

```
Private Function heythere(blah As String)
    extraBit = "title"
    ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, ")", "," & """" & extraBit & """" & ")")
End Function
```

Basically that `extraBit` is defined by a UserForm ListBox if the user doesn't add it into the formula. There are many options, loaded dynamically into the ListBox based on the first argument of the entry. It's a little tricky to explain, but if the `extraBit` is provided in the formula then it means the UserForm doesn't appear and the result is given directly. So I want to "repair" the entry after the `extraBit` is defined. Essentially, in the example above, `=heythere(a1)` would become `=heythere(a1,"title")`.

Is this possible? I tried creating a separate Private Sub to overwrite the entry, to no avail. Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

---

Edit: To clarify how it is intended to work, the actual UDF is more like this, with an optional secondary argument:

```
Private Function heythere2(blah As String, Optional extraBit As String)
    If extraBit = "" Then
        extraBit = "title"
        ActiveCell.Formula = Replace(ActiveCell.Formula, ")", "," & """" & extraBit & """" & ")")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case.  Why not just have an optional second parameter for heythere?

Comment: Sorry, I've removed the second parameter ... let me add it back in and elaborate slightly on how it works...

Comment: Hm, what if: Save your formula as a String. Then, use whatever method to update that string with your `extraBit`.  Then, you can do `Cells(1,1).Formula = myString`?  In your example, is it working even? Or are you getting errors?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... this behaves the same sadly. It doesn't work, doesn't give an error - it just thinks for a second; doesn't update the formula, and returns #VALUE! which is understandable because my function example has no result. I can *make* it resolve to something but it still doesn't change the formula.

Comment: I could make it return the intended formula as a value result, then ask the user to copy + paste values only, then F2+enter on the cell to set the function again.........hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is excel has no clue what you intend to do with the formula and the return value is not valid.  This will show you that you are encountering an error. if this is a UDF you are entering an endless loop as each time the cell changes it runs the code again.  Rethink your approach.

```
Public Function heythere(blah As String, Optional extraBit As String = "")
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim formulaText As String
    formulaText = ActiveCell.Formula
    If extraBit = "" Then
        extraBit = "title"
    End If
    formulaText = Replace(formulaText, ")", "," & Chr(34) & extraBit & Chr(34) & ")")
    ActiveCell.Formula = formulaText

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
End Function
```

So lets change your formula  bit and use the worksheet change event

```
'Lets set the text of the cell to the value of the extrabit
Public Function heythere(blah As String, Optional extraBit As String = "") As String
    If extraBit = "" Then
        extraBit = "title"
    End If
    heythere = extraBit
End Function
```

Now we update the formula using our worksheet changed event

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If InStr(1, Target.Formula, ",") > 0 Then

    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim formulaText As String
        formulaText = Target.Formula

        formulaText = Replace(formulaText, ")", "," & Chr(34) & Target.Value & Chr(34) & ")")
        Target.Formula = formulaText

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox Err.Description
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Viola, the Formula is updated.  IMO this is still a bad approach as then you would need to do some checking for which formula is in the cell before you act on it.

Comment: Thank you very much - Sorceri by name... :-) this works, amazing. I am working on the check procedure to make it as tight as possible. Thank you!